# pressing button on html, Flask doesn't do anything

Tags: python, html, flask, request, vps

I have a website with one button. While button is pressed I would like to get message out using Flask.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask import request


app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/")
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return 'yes it works'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Any idea why nothing happens? Why when I press button, i don't get message "yes it works"?.

html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Page</title>
<meta name="generator" content="WYSIWYG Web Builder 11 - http://www.wysiwygwebbuilder.com">
<link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/Untitled3.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/index.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<input type="submit" id="Button1" name="" value="Submit" style="position:absolute;left:382px;top:298px;width:96px;height:25px;z-index:0;">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things

1. You have a duplicate route in your python

You may want to do

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
  return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/login", methods=['POST'])
def login():
  if request.method == 'POST':
    return 'yes it works'
```

And your html wrap your button in a `<form>` element

```
<body>
<form action="/login" method="post">
<input type="submit" id="Button1" name="" value="Submit" style="position:absolute;left:382px;top:298px;width:96px;height:25px;z-index:0;">
</form>
</body>
```